# Disable Access to Node.js Source Code files in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm building a basic website with Node.js, and I don't want anyone to be able to access my server-side source code (it contains login credentials for a database). My main application is in a file called 'app.js' in the root directory where the application is run. If I browse to mysite.com/app.js, the source code file is served. Is there a way to disallow access to certain files with Node.js or just in general? The site is hosted on Microsoft Azure, if that makes a difference (my research seems to indicate that Microsoft and Apache handle this differently).

Comment: how is this hosted in Azure? VM? App Service?

Comment: You can use Environment variables or dotEnv package(by putting .env file in .gitignore).

Comment: @Alex It's hosted in an app service

Comment: how did you deploy it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, Azure uses IIS to serve your Node.js app. So, you'll need to add the IIS configuration file called `web.config` to app's root folder to restrict access to the server-side source code.

### *web.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
          <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
          <webSocket enabled="false" />
          <handlers>
               <!-- Indicates that the app.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
               <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
          </handlers>
          <rewrite>
               <rules>
                    <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
                    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">                    
                        <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                    </rule>

                    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
                    <rule name="StaticContent">
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                    </rule>

                    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
                    <rule name="DynamicContent">
                         <conditions>
                              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                         </conditions>
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
                    </rule>
               </rules>
          </rewrite>

          <!-- bin directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
          <security>
               <requestFiltering>
                    <hiddenSegments>
                         <remove segment="bin"/>
                    </hiddenSegments>
               </requestFiltering>
          </security>

          <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
          <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

          <!--
               You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
                 * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
                 * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
                 * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

               To debug your node.js application:
                 * set the debuggingEnabled option to "true"
                 * enable web sockets from the portal at https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/WebsiteExtension/Website/aarontestnode/configure
                 * browse to https://aarontestnode.azurewebsites.net/app.js/debug/

               See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
          -->
          <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js" debuggingEnabled="false" />
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

In app service you can declare key value pairs including connection strings in the "Application Settings" blade. The same will be available as environment variables for Java, Node, PHP and Python applications. This way they will be secure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure

Answer (score -1):

2 problems here:

- Restricting Access To Static Files
- Protecting Credential Information

## Restricting Access To Static Files

Both with Apache and Nginx it is possible to specify how to serve static assets. requests for static assets should map to a specific assets folder. So that requests to `yourdomainname.com/myfile.js` will map to `/path/to/static/assets/myfile.js`. Research their docs to see how to to this.

## Protecting Credential Information

You need to keep your credential information (API Key, Database password, etc...) outside of your code repo. To do this, you can use `.env` files with the [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: So as long as someone knows the path to my node.js files, they can be accessed? Should I just make the path really obfuscated to lower the risks of some user brute forcing it? Ideally, yourdomainname.com/app.js would return a 404.

Comment: You misunderstood my answer. The whole point is to never expose your source files. With the method I have indicated, nobody will never have acess to your source files. You dont need to obfuscate anything. The example I put was to show you that any attempt to access a source file will result in nginx trying to serve this file from the static path you put in nginx config - path which is supposed to NOT contain any sensitive source files, but only the publicly accessible assets (images, css, etc..)